# chrome.sessions.getRecentlyClosed not using filter

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am using the following function in order to get recently closed sessions https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sessions#method-getRecentlyClosed .

The docs say that I can pass a filter object with a property of maxResults in order to restrict the number of sessions return. I am not setting it over the supposed max of 25. But alas, code doesn't seem to work correctly; I'm expecting sessions array to contain 5 elements, but I still get 25 items ( I do get a response, it's just not being filtered properly).

```
// extension.js
// for now, hardcode limit of 5 for testing purposes
function getAllSessions(callback) {
  chrome.sessions.getRecentlyClosed({maxResults: 5}, function(sessions) {
    callback(sessions);
  });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    getAllSessions(function(sessions) {
        console.debug(sessions)
    });
});
```

simple html that loads the script

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="extension.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong. I'm leaning towards this being an actual bug, but my favorite search engine doesn't have any results on this bug, or even a lot of people using this API.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: In addition to the additional code (minimum is a *manifest.json* and defining what `callback` function you used), the problem description "code doesn't seem to work" is *almost never* sufficient all by itself. What, *exactly* did you expect it to do? What *exactly* did it do that was not to your expectations?

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that we want to help. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate all the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: I appreciate your encouragement to make the question better, but there are plenty of questions with less detail that still get a reply from someone that's actually worked with that code. Given that I'm using an api that takes a filter with a property called MAXRESULTS, I felt it was unnecessary to qualify the statement "code doesn't seem to work" as it is obvious to a coder that maxresults not working means that its not respecting the max results parameter. However I've edited to make it explicitly clear in case people who have never worked with chrome extensions want to help.

Comment: Did you find the solution to the answer? I've encountered the same problem lately and I just couldn't find any answers to the problem yet.

Comment: @AngusZhu I've shelved this project for awhile now, and don't think I ever got a solution. I doubt it's a bug, as it would have probably been reported by now. Hope you find a solution. I probably won't look at this code for awhile, but when I do, and if I find a solution, I'll be sure to respond here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There are just too few documents or references on the Internet. My current workaround is to splice the returned array on my own.

Comment: I didn't find anything on that bug either. No matter what value < 25 I use for the maxResults filter, I still get exactly 25 results. If the value is > 25 I get an error explaining the max allowed is 25 - so I know the filter is using correct syntax, it's just being ignored.